# Insert comment content with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to insert my comment content with Ajax. But I believe I'm having trouble with the comment_add.php page and wondered if someone could take a look for me.

Getting the streamid seems to work as I've checked in firebug, but it shows no content. So I don't know whether I may have missed something that I can't see but someone else might be able to find. Or maybe I just haven't written the comment_add page properly.

FORM

```
echo "<form id='addcomment' method='POST' class='form_statusinput'>
<input type='hidden' name='posterid' id='posterid' value='".$user1_id."'>
<input type='hidden' name='streamid' id='streamid' value='".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>
<input name='content' id='content' placeholder='Comment..' autocomplete='off'>
<input type='submit' id='button' value='Feed'>
</form>";
```

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#addcomment").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var content = $("#content").val();
var streamid = $("#streamid").val();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "comment_add.php",
dataType: "json",
data: {content:content,streamid:streamid}, 
success: function(response){ 
$("#commentaddid").prepend(""+content+"");
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

COMMENT_ADD.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require"include/load.php";
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
if(isset($_POST['streamid'])&isset($_POST['content'])){
if($_POST['content']){
rawfeeds_user_core::add_comment($_POST['streamid'],$_POST['content']);
}
}
?>
```

FUNCTION

```
public function add_comment($streamid,$content){
            $content =  mysql_real_escape_string($content);
            $content =  strip_tags($content);

            $content = preg_replace('/(?<!S)((http(s?):\/\/)|(www.))+([\w.1-9\&=#?\-~%;\/]+)/','<a href="http$3://$4$5">http$3://$4$5</a>', $content);

            if(strlen($content)>0){
            $insert = "INSERT INTO streamdata_comments(comment_poster, comment_streamitem, comment_datetime, comment_content) VALUES (".$_SESSION['id'].",$streamid,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'$content')";
                        echo $insert;

            $add_post = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
success: function(response){ 
$("#commentaddid").prepend(""+content+"");
}
```

to

```
success: function(response){ 
$("#commentaddid").prepend(""+response+"");
}
```

because content doesn't exist in that function

AND

your links wouldn't be `<a>`'s

EDIT 2
Because you wanted to add the data from the other side here is a little hack you can use to get content

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "comment_add.php", 
dataType: "json",
_content:content,
data: {content:content,streamid:streamid},  
success: function(response){  
    $("#commentaddid").prepend(""+this._content+""); 
} 
});
```

This is possible because the constructor loop through the object and sets it to this

Comment: Actually response would only be used if you're calling data. I can use VAR content as its already been added as content into the database. 

Your solution hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick. Thankyou @EaterOfCorpses. It works now. 
What is the constructor loop? Why did I have to do that?

Comment: No i was trying to explain that the constructor is just `function(options){for(i in options){this[i] = options[i];}}`

Answer (score 0):

Your input field "content" markup is missing **value** and **type** attribute. Type is not crucial as it defaults to text but always better to explicitly specify.

```
<input name="content" type="text" value="" id="content" placeholder="Comment.." autocomplete="off" />
```